# Error TypeError: GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I try running my WhatsApp Bots using whatsapp-web.js module and making if Admins using a .setSMAO (Send Messages Admin Only) true, it will automatically set the Group Settings Send Messages to Admin Only

I search the methods on https://docs.wwebjs.dev/GroupChat.html and found GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly();

I tried adding it and then test it but instead of working, I just met this error

```
GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly();
          ^

TypeError: GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\WhatsApp Bots keenan\bot.js:240:14)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The code:

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
    const chat = await msg.getChat();
    const contact = await msg.getContact();

    if (msg.body == '.setSMAO true') {
        if (chat.isGroup) {
            let chat = await msg.getChat();
            GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly();
            msg.reply('Successfully changed the Group Settings.');
            console.log('[CHANGED_SEND_MESSAGE_TO_ADMIN_ONLY] There was an Admin that changed the Group Settings Send Message to Admin Only');
        } else {
            msg.reply('This command only works on Group or the Bot didn't have an Admin Permissions!');
        }
    } 
});
```

What did I do? Did I just typing it wrong?

Comment: Replace `GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly()` with `chat.setMessagesAdminsOnly()` and it should work.

Comment: It works! Thanks! You should add it as an Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupChat is an class/constructor for chats where Messages can appear, similar to [Chat](https://docs.wwebjs.dev/Chat.html). And instances of them will be returned on a message with `message.getChat()`.

You already did the right part with the check for `chat.isGroup`, so all you have to do afterwards is calling `groupChatInstance.setMessagesAdminsOnly()` which is possible on the same referrence by replacing `GroupChat.setMessagesAdminsOnly()` with `chat.setMessagesAdminsOnly()`.